# SPICE model for PMBFJ309

Tags: ltspice, spice

Does anyone knows where I can find SPICE model for PMBFJ309 or similar? I searched a lot and could not find. If anyone knows, could you please share the link.

Comment: Who makes the PMBFJ309? NXP does. Is there a model that you can download from NXP's PMBFJ309 product page? No. Then chances are, there is no model. Note that this is an N-channel JFET. JFETs aren't used that much and there few different models. I would look for JFETs on Mouser and then see which manufacturers have models for their JFETs. Then see which of those is the most similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are:

[Browse Cadence PSpice Model Library](https://www.pspice.com/discrete/jfets?page=20) (as of May 19, 2021)

[image: pmbfj309]

Comment: Can you download it? All I get is a list. But I think the problem will be the license.

Comment: @concerned You are right, this is the list of Cadence's Pspice models available for authorized users. Use this "colophon" of the referenced publication to find the way to get hold of the actual model data.